# How can i get document id in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

How can i get document id which 'content' is 'test2' ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUmka.png)
i try like this.. but the condition does not work.

```
 ref.where(ref.doc('content') == 'test2').get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
      snapshot.docs.forEach((document){
        print(document.id);
      });
 });
```

How can I get document id of specific document?
(I use flutter and cloud firestore)

Comment: Please share the rest of your code. And start with changing `'content'` to `'contents'`. In firebase you have it sotred as 'contents' with an `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming`ref` is your collection reference, use this:

```
await ref.where('contents', isEqualTo: 'test2').get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
      snapshot.docs.forEach((document){
        print(document.id);
      });
 });
```

Comment: You're most welcome! Please consider marking this as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo in your field name, it's `contents` in the screenshot but `content` in your code. So that'll lead to empty snapshots.

```
ref.where(ref.doc('contents') == 'test2').get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
      snapshot.docs.forEach((document){
        print(document.id);
      });
 });
```

Also make sure the value of ref is `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('post')`.

PS: You can also use this syntax.
`ref.where("contents", isEqualTo: "post2").get()`